# ATmega644P programming via STLINK v2

Tags: atmega, st-link, ide

I want to upload program/debug ATmega644P using STlinkV2(JTAG). Is it possible? Which IDE support make debug ATmega644 using STlinkV2.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

The stlink "speaks" SWD, whereas the atmega uses a completely different, incompatible, debug- and programming-interface.

By the way, the stlink v2 itself contains a microcontroller multiple times more powerful than an atmega644.